# Quick you have 5 seconds on your clock, what’s your move?

Tags: online-chess, puzzles, bullet-chess

Here is the position:
[image: interesting position]

What would you do if you only had 5 seconds on the clock?

Answer (score 2):

The first moves I look at, at any speed, are the checks.

Being human, under the pressure, I would play Qxf6+, as it also gains material (although it only leads to a draw). Qxc8+ also fits my criteria, but it moves the queen farther away, which just doesn't seem right.

The correct answer for the mate=in-two was aleady given but deleted by the post author.

Comment: Why does Qxf6+ lead to a draw? After ...Qf7 Qxh8+ Qg8 Qxg8+ White is up an exchange and two pawns and will win eventually.

Comment: Qxf6+ is completely winning lol, you're up an exchange and two pawns. Granted the opponent has SOME counterplay, as long as you're a decent endgame player you'll win with almost no calculation. I could win that position even if I have only 30 seconds on the clock.

Comment: With 5 seconds on the clock, I wouldn't be looking for a win but a perpetual check, therefore the game, not the position, would be a draw.  Lots of luck.